# Segmentation fault in recursive program

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, coin-change

I am doing the coin problem, the problem says that,

> Given a set of coin values `coins = {c1, c2,..., ck}` and a target sum
> of money `n`, our task is to form the sum `n` using as few coins as
> possible.

suppose you have 9 dollars and you have set of `{6,5,1}` so, the minimum no. of sum/change for 9 dollars would be `( 6+1+1+1=9)` i.e. `4`.

i tried doing it recursively using  this formula :

```
solve(x) = min( solve(x−6)+1, solve(x−5)+1, solve(x−1)+1 )
```

,but I don't know why I'm getting Segmentation fault in my code.

There are plenty of codes available online, but I want to know what am I doing wrong here, I'm new to recursion please help me, The code goes here:

```
//my code

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int solve (int x, int a[], int n)
{
  if (x < 0)
    {
      return INT_MAX;
    }
  if (x == 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
  int best = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      best = min (best, solve (x - a[i], a, n) + 1);
    }
  return best;
}

int main ()
{
int a[] = { 6, 5, 1 };
int x = 9;
int n = 3;
cout << solve (x, a, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Did you try to run your program in your debugger and see where the segmentation fault happens?

Comment: Something that caught my eye immediately: you never once touch `a` in your recursive function--that doesn't feel right.

Comment: You are always passing x as the same value, because i starts with 0 (9-0 == 9)

Comment: `solve (x - i, a, n)` should be `solve (x - a[i], a, n)`. But there are probably some other problems. `solve` returns `INT_MAX` in some cases. You add 1 to it. Do you know what than happens? For signed values the behavior is not defined.

Comment: @scohe001 sorry,by mistake i wrote a[i] as i

Comment: @Thomas Sabik  ya, you are right , either I have to keep a check  or should replace statement if(x<0) return INT_MAX; because on adding 1 overflow will occur....am I correct?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I just corrected it.

Comment: @Quimby ya I did and I'm getting  "-2147483647[Inferior 1 (process 6076) exited normally]  ".

Comment: You should probably read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @ThomasSablik I did this on a online compiler, when I debugged I got  this message-"2147483647[Inferior 1 (process 6076) exited normally] ",I think the INT_MAX thing is causing problem.

Comment: Which online compiler has a debugger? I think the most important step for you is to learn what a debugger is and how to use it. A programmer doesn't guess what the actual problem is. A programmer analyzes the problem and knows what the problem is.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Actually [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) has a decent debugger.

Comment: @cigien I didn't say there is no online IDE with debugger but since OP isn't able to locate the line of the segmentation fault and to give more information I assume that OP's online IDE doesn't have a debugger or that OP doesn't know how to use it. But you are right. My question _"Which online compiler has a debugger?"_ could imply that there is no online IDE with debugger.

Comment: it should be `solve(x) = 1 + min( solve(x−6), solve(x−5), solve(x−1) )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which have been took from: *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-make-a-change/*

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int minCoins(int coins[], int m, int amount) {
        if (amount == 0) return 0;

        int res = INT_MAX;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (coins[i] <= amount) {
                int sub_res = minCoins(coins, m, amount - coins[i]);

                if (sub_res != INT_MAX && sub_res + 1 < res) { // avoid overflow 
                    res = sub_res + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    int main() {
        int coins[] = { 6, 5, 1 };
        int amount = 9;
        cout << "Min coins is " 
             << minCoins(coins, sizeof(coins) / sizeof(coins[0]), amount) 
             << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

About the problem:

1. Your Segmentation fault comes from the line:
   `best = min (best, solve (x - i, a, n) + 1);`
   The reason is: `x-i` will always gives you the same value so if you are run the program without debugging, your program crashing. So don't try to debug it because it will takes a lot of time to see this crashing.
   For starters change to: `best = min (best, solve (x - a[i], a, n) + 1);`.
2. After fixing the section 1, the if case: `if (x < 0) return INT_MAX;` will causes problem and will return always the same value, which is: `-INT_MAX`. So you need to check the "if cases" again.
3. The algorithm you try to implement is not correct, see the pseudo-code of this algorithm:

   ```
    minchange(M):
      if M = 0:
        return 0
      v <- infinity
      for c in denominations <= M:
         v <- min { minchange(M - c) + 1, v }
      return v
   ```
4. Better use: `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` instead of `int n = 3`.

Comment: Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou so much.....it really helped me :-),that a[i] thing was a typing mistake  , I corrected it later.